# Include `.scss` file in another `.scss` file?

Tags: sass, scss-lint

How can I Include `.scss` file in another `.scss` file?
I was trying to write this in a file:
app.scss:

```
@include('buttons');
@include('dropzone');

body {

    background: $primaryColor;
    overflow-x: hidden; /*Clip the left/right edges of the content inside the <div> element - if it overflows the element's content area: */
    height: 100%; /* Cover all (100%) of the container for the body with its content */
    padding-top: 70px;
} /* more css code here */
```

and it returns an error : `invalid css after @import`

I try to include 2 other scss files inside the main `scss` file, so it will be all compiled to one `css` file eventually. How is it possible?

Answer (score 50):

You can import it like this;

```
@import "../../_variables";

@import "../_mixins";

@import "_main";

@import "_login";

@import "_exception";

@import "_utils";

@import "_dashboard";

@import "_landing";
```

According to your directories and it will do what you want.

Comment: I did. And compilation with gulp does not throw any errors.The thing's that the style is not applied to the page at all.

Comment: You need to precompile your sass folder to css folder then include your compiled css to your page.

Answer (score 10):

You can include a partial by doing this:

```
@import "partial";
```

The imported file needs an underscore, so sass will recognize it to be included: _partial.scss

Comment: thanks for that.It returns another error:  ```gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Sass Compilation Failed: resources/assets/sass/app.scss
Error: @import directive requires a url or quoted path
        on line 4 of stdin
>> @import('buttons');
   ^```
Tried to run both:
```
npm install -g gulp-sass and npm install gulp-sass 
```
still getting the same error as above.

Comment: and both files are in the same directory?

Comment: updated my answer, check if your partial starts with an underscore

Comment: Just to point out `_` is not a requirement. Sass ignores the `_partials` in output, but if provided without it, it'll create corresponding CSS for the partial as well

Comment: True, but you'd like to have all scss compiled in one css file

Comment: Still does not apply to my view. Even though no erros are thrown during compiling to .css file.

Comment: Then you might have a different issue. You sure your scss doesn't have any mistakes?

Comment: I think it does not have since it is able to import all mixins, and also gulp does not throw an error when I am compling to css file. any other thing you think I can check on?

Comment: Issue with gulp. See here for more info: https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/1

Answer (score 10):

You can use **@use** rule for it. This rule loads another Sass file as a module, which means you can refer to its variables, mixins, and functions in your Sass file with a namespace based on the filename. Using a file will also include the CSS it generates in your compiled output!

```
// _base.scss
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

see how to using **@use** 'base'; in the **styles.scss** file

```
// styles.scss
@use 'base';

.inverse {
  background-color: base.$primary-color;
  color: white;
}
```

you don't need to include the file extension.

Comment: @osherdo Please promote this as the valid answer. Most of the ranked answers are out-of-date due to `@import` support.
The Sass team **discourages the continued use of the @import rule**. Sass will gradually **phase it out over the next few years, and eventually remove it** from the language entirely...[source](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)

Answer (score 2):

@osherdo You have no need to add `!important` for overwriting bootstrap CSS.

```
body 
{
background: #4d94ff; /* Use to override Bootstrap css settings. */
}
```

First of you need to verify from where bootstrap is rendering on the page and what is the weight of the bootstrap CSS file. After that you can place your `'css/app.css'` file after bootstrap then it will work. Then you can easily overwrite the entire bootstrap CSS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it appears to be that my `app.scss` file collide with Bootstrap.css file.
Because I wanted the `app.scss` `background` property to apply, instead of the bootstrap css file. I've added `!important` in this property to override bootstrap style.:

```
body 
{
background: #4d94ff !important; /* Used to override Bootstrap css settings. */
}
```

Also, `gulpfile.js` has been updated to suite my needs accordingly:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');


elixir(function (mix) {
mix.sass('app.scss', 'resources/assets/css')
 .styles([
'app.css'
 ], 'public/css/app.css');
 mix.version([
   'css/app.css'
    ]);
 });
```

And that's how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@forward()` or `@use` and the name of the file you want to include should begin with a underscore, then the file doesn't get compiled to a css file. Only the file where you include the files should be compiled to a css file.