# SCSS/SASS not working in MicroFront End using React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, micro-frontend

Hello I am new to MicroFront End in React JS. I am trying to work on SCSS with MicroFront End in React JS. I have 2 files.

1: _variable.scss
2:style.scss

below is my code which I want to work in my application.

```
//_variable.scss

$base-color: #c6538c;

:export{
    baseColor:$base-color;
}
```

```
//style.scss

@import url('_variable.scss');

body{
    background: $base-color;
}
```

I am assigning a background value to Body of the application. but it is not working.

Any help would be Great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709630/include-scss-file-in-another-scss-file)
You see that you don't need to use the `url()` method, Try changing your `style.scss` file to

```
@import '_variable';

body {
    background: $base-color;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried, but it is not working.

Comment: How about changing the `background: $base-color;` to `background: $baseColor;` in style.scss

Comment: I did. but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to explicitly export your variable. So, what you can do is:

```
//variable.scss

$base_color: #c6538c;
```

and:

```
//style.scss

@import 'variable.scss';

body{
    background: $base_color;
}
```

Also be careful with importing:

- if "style.scss" is in the same directory with "variable.scss" then you should import like this:

  @import "./variable.scss"

Comment: Thank You for your answer. but it is not working.. I have implemented MicroFrontEnd so may be that is the case , is it not working ?

Comment: @BhavinShah if that's the case you can try to import "style.scss" into that particular layout or into the main file where your html is located for that particular frontEnd.